# Perl unpack "S*" equivalent in C

Tags: c, perl

I'm having a little trouble understanding Perl's unpack in some code I'm reading, specifically with the `S*` template.

```
$data = "FF";
print "$data - ", unpack("S*", $data), "\n";
# > FF - 17990
```

1. What is the equivalent of this in C?
2. Why?

Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Run `perldoc -f unpack` for info about the unpack function, and it points you to `perldoc -f pack` for explanations about the different formats.  Also, note that "FF" is not the hex value 0xFF if that's what you're expecting.

Comment: Ah, reading up on `pack` was what I needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code in C would look (roughly) like this:

```
const char *data = "FA";
unsigned short s;
memcpy( &s, data, strlen(data) );
printf("%s = %d\n", data, s);
```

This only handles your case with two characters, while unpack('S*',...) will return a list of shorts corresponding to its input.

Why? One of the primary motivations for pack and unpack was to make it easier interchange binary data with C structures.

[perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: We posted our answers at the same time :). Thanks for the C example—that will be really helpful. I’ll mark yours as the accepted answer since it more directly answers the question.

Comment: I agree and probably should have removed it in the last edit, but I left it because the answer had been accepted with that code.

Answer (score 3):

`unpack 'S'` casts two bytes into a `uint16_t`.

```
#include <stdint.h>
const char *data = "\x46\x41";
uint16_t n;
memcpy(&n, data, sizeof(n));  // n = 0x4146 or 0x4641
```

Don't forget to check the number of bytes in `data` before doing this!

---

Notice that it can give two different results based on the system.

On a little-endian system (e.g. x86, x64), `unpack 'S'` is also equivalent to

```
uint16_t n = (data[1] << 8) | data[0];  // 0x4146
```

On a big-endian system, `unpack 'S'` is also equivalent to

```
uint16_t n = (data[0] << 8) | data[1];  // 0x4641
```

---

By the way, you might be tempted to do the following, but it's not portable due to memory alignment issues:

```
uint16_t n = *((const uint16_t *)data);
```

Comment: The bitshifting parts of this answer in the middle are the only safe way to do it. Best not to do any of the silly casting parts like the top or bottom bits.

Comment: The `memcpy` itself will be fine, but now you've got some random bit-pattern of bytes in memory where the compiler is expecting a valid `uint16_t`. How do you know the bitpattern will be valid as that type?
There's no danger of that when you let the compiler construct the `uint16_t` by numerical bitshift operations, because it knows it will be valid then

Comment: @ikagami - could be all sorts. C doesn't require that all possible bit-patterns of bytes are valid integer representations. They just happen to be so on, say, Linux x86_64 gcc, but that's a platform-specific guarantee.

Comment: On platforms that Perl supports, perhaps it is true. But C _itself_ can support some very very strange places, and these places may not validly hold that you can just copy bits around and make it work.

Comment: @LeoNerd, `unpack 'S'` uses *native* representation of a `uint16_t`. As such, you're actually arguing that `memcpy` is the only correct solution.

Comment: @LeoNerd, I doubt your claims about the existence of a system that uses something other than one's complement or two's complement. This is your fourth chance to back up your claims of the existence of something else.

Answer (score 1):

I’m answering my own question, so I might have some things wrong, but I'll leave this here for anyone coming in the future.

First, let's change my example to

```
$data = "FA";
print "$data - ", unpack("S*", $data), "\n";
# > FA - 16710
```

since having “FF” wasn’t particularly helpful.

The question is: how did we get from “FA” to 16710?

First, the character ‘F’ is converted to its ASCII value—70. In binary, this is `0100 0110` (note that I padded a leading zero so it’s clear that it’s a whole byte).

Then, we need the ASCII value of ‘A’—65. In binary, `0100 0001`.

So we have `F` corresponding to `0100 0110` and `A` corresponding to `0100 0001`.

Then we just glue these two binary values together, *except* we put the `A` first:

`0100 0001 0100 0110`

And converting `0100 0001 0100 0110` to decimal gives `16,710`.

**Note**: I *think* the order in which the bytes are glued together might be different on different computers, so while the principle here should apply everywhere, the numbers might be different.

Comment: Byte order is important -- "S" is an unsigned short in the _system's_ byte order. If you need big or little endian you'll use "n" or "v" respectively.